# Li hover but change color in anchor tag

Tags: css, hover

I'm fiddling with a Wordpress navigation. I have a navigation where in hover state the background of each li item turns orange and the text is meant to turn white from black.

It appears though that there are 3 colors going on. With no hover the `<a>` is black, when the `<li>` item is hovered over the `<a>` tag text is grey and when you hover the very middle, the `<a>` tag, the color of the text is white.

There should be two colors for the anchor text: black for default and white when hovered. I need to stop the grey so that when the orange is activated, so too is the white text.

There are a few pieces of code from this Wordpress site that could be relevant. I'm guessing these ones below but cannot see where I would edit for this particular issue. If anyone can offer a pointer the website is here, I'm not even sure what I should be trying to select:

tinyurl.com/m562wgd

```
/*     2.2.1 Top Drop-down menu */
    .dropdown ul,
    .dropdown ul li,
    .dropdown ul ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
```

and

```
.dropdown ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.dropdown ul li.hover,
.dropdown ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown the CSS that changes the color of the anchor.

Comment: none of that mentions colors so you'll have to dig deeper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grey is coming from the li changing opacity. You only see the white when you hover over the anchor tag because that is the Only place you have the hover set

Add

```
.dropdown ul li:hover a {
  color: white;
}
```

That should do it

Comment: Thank you for helping out, it looks great now

Answer (score 1):

There is no gray, just an opacity change in the rule:

```
.dropdown ul li.hover, .dropdown ul li:hover, .dropdown ul li.on {
    background-color: orange;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Which makes the black appear to be gray. You also want to add the following rule to make the link white when you hover over the list item:

```
.dropdown ul li:hover a {
    color: white;
}
```